# Prove there is no one-to-one correspondence function $\colon X→ P(X)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm stuck on the following question and would appreciate it if someone could show me how I can prove it.

Let $X$ be any set and let $P(X)$ be the power set containing all subsets of $X$.

Prove there is no one-to-one correspondence   $f\colon X → P(X)$

Would I use the fact that $|X|=n$, so that $|P(X)|=2^n$, to form a proof?

Thanks.

Comment: Cantor's theorem, a pretty fundamental result. Surely this is proven in your class/textbook/course notes/...? It's the classic "diagonal argument". I'd be very surprised if you were asked to prove this starting from nothing. Your notation $|X| = n$ suggests that $X$ is finite, but $X$ can be any set whatsoever.

Comment: If your set is finite, all you need to do is to show that $2^n\gt n$.

Comment: @BrianO One-to-one correspondence (≠ one-to-one function) refers to a bijection.

Comment: @JulienGodawatta It's potentially ambiguous. 1-1 means injective, but ... yeah adding "correspondence" does change things, so.I accept that I was splitting hairs. I deleted that comment.

Comment: @BrianO It's more a case of unfortunate terminology. Silly mathematicians!

Comment: @ OP However, if you know that $X$ is finite, then yes you can use the fact that $|P(X)| = 2^n$ and prove the result that @AndréNicolas mentioned.

Comment: Let $A = \{x \in X \mid x \not \in f(x) \}$. Prove that there can be no $a \in X$ for which $f(a) = A$. (Would $a \in A$?)